# Helping others succeed

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, kiruv-outreach

What do you do when you are trying to help friends get themselves on a good track, but you are afraid that by helping them you yourself might fall...what is the Torah obligation here?

Answer (score 4):

Speak to someone else who can help and won't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Nida discusses what a person should do with his nails. The Gemara there says that "chossid sorfan" - that a pious person should burn them so that a pregnant woman wouldn't accidentally step on uncovered nails. Tosfos says that this is true despite the damage one receives for burning parts of one's body. Therefore, we see that one should be willing to undergo a definite self-harm for the partial benefit of another.

If this is true physically, all the more so spiritually.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's saying that burning ones nails causes damage to the person even when they're _not_ still connected to their hands. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, just give them advice or go to someone else to help your friend